# TableViewController data is empty in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

- I am very new to `iOS programming`
- I am trying to fetch data from Yelp's API and present that in `UITableViewCell`
- My code looks like

> ```
> @interface SearchResultViewController ()
> @property(nonatomic, strong) YelpClient *client;
> @property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *searchResultTableView;
> @property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray *businesses;
> @end
>
> @implementation SearchResultViewController
>
> - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
>     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
>     if (self) {
>         NSLog(@"fetching businesses");
>         [self fetchBusinesses];
>
>     }
>     return self;
> }
>
> - (void)fetchBusinesses {
>     // You can register for Yelp API keys here: http://www.yelp.com/developers/manage_api_keys
>     self.client = [[YelpClient alloc] initWithConsumerKey:kYelpConsumerKey
> ```
>
> consumerSecret:kYelpConsumerSecret accessToken:kYelpToken
>   accessSecret:kYelpTokenSecret];
>
> ```
>     [self.client searchWithTerm:@"Thai" success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
>         self.businesses = response[@"businesses"];
>         [self.searchResultTableView reloadData];
>         NSLog(@"businesses count (after fetch): %d", self.businesses.count);
>     }                   failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
>         NSLog(@"error: %@", [error description]);
>     }];
> }
>
> - (void)viewDidLoad {
>     [super viewDidLoad];
>
>     self.searchResultTableView.dataSource = self;
>     self.searchResultTableView.delegate = self;
>
>     UITableViewController *uiTableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
>     uiTableViewController.tableView = _searchResultTableView;
>
>     NSLog(@"view loaded");
> }
>
> - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
>     return 5;
> }
>
> - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
>     RestaurantViewCell *restaurantViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RestaurantViewCell"];
>     if (restaurantViewCell == nil) {
>         restaurantViewCell = [[RestaurantViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
> ```
>
> reuseIdentifier:@"RestaurantViewCell"];
>           }
>
> ```
>     NSLog(@"businesses count (for cell view): %d", self.businesses.count);
>     restaurantViewCell.textLabel.text = @"Osha's Thai";
>     return restaurantViewCell;
> }
> @end
> ```

When I run my application, I see the following in log

```
2014-06-19 09:51:57.447 yelp[15415:70b] fetching businesses
2014-06-19 09:51:57.483 yelp[15415:70b] view loaded
2014-06-19 09:51:57.485 yelp[15415:70b] businesses count (for cell view): 0
2014-06-19 09:51:57.486 yelp[15415:70b] businesses count (for cell view): 0
2014-06-19 09:51:57.487 yelp[15415:70b] businesses count (for cell view): 0
2014-06-19 09:51:57.487 yelp[15415:70b] businesses count (for cell view): 0
2014-06-19 09:51:57.487 yelp[15415:70b] businesses count (for cell view): 0
2014-06-19 09:51:57.900 yelp[15415:70b] businesses count (after fetch): 20
```

**Questions**
- It seems that fetching data is asynchronous, so I get last line as

```
2014-06-19 09:51:57.900 yelp[15415:70b] businesses count (after fetch): 20
```

- But meanwhile `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is already called and the data is `nil`

How do I handle this situation to make sure that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called when we have data?

- I am also using `[self.searchResultTableView reloadData];` but not sure if that is doing right thing

Comment: Move the `fetchBusinesses` call into `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: That did not do anything extra actually

Comment: I didn't say that would solve your problem. It's something you should do because you'll have problems if your request returns before your view is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is being called because you told the table that there are cells to display.

This...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}
```

Should be...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.businesses.count;
}
```

Comment: cool, but then, I do not see ` NSLog(@"businesses count (for cell view): %d", self.businesses.count);` in my log anymore, means it is not called?

Comment: It means your table view is not being reloaded. Check to make sure your table view is not nil and that it's data source is your class.

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` returns `0` because async call is not complete yet. How to handle such situation?

Comment: Just noticed that you don't do anything with your UITableViewController in your viewDidLoad.

Comment: You don't want to show cells when you don't have data yet. That's why you return 0.

Comment: then what do I need to do when I have data? how do I show them up in cells?

Comment: I added new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312642/tableviewcontroller-async-call-numberofrowsinsection-returns-0