# TableViewController: Async call, numberOfRowsInSection returns 0

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am new to `iOS programming`
My first question is listed [TableViewController data is empty in cellForRowAtIndexPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312174/tableviewcontroller-data-is-empty-in-cellforrowatindexpath)

Upon suggestions, I made changes to code which looks like

```
@interface SearchResultViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) YelpClient *client;
@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *searchResultTableView;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray *businesses;
@end

@implementation SearchResultViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)fetchBusinesses {
    // You can register for Yelp API keys here: http://www.yelp.com/developers/manage_api_keys
    self.client = [[YelpClient alloc] initWithConsumerKey:kYelpConsumerKey consumerSecret:kYelpConsumerSecret accessToken:kYelpToken accessSecret:kYelpTokenSecret];

    [self.client searchWithTerm:@"Thai" success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
        self.businesses = response[@"businesses"];

        NSLog(@"businesses count (after fetch): %d", self.businesses.count);
    }                   failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error description]);
    }];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchResultTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.searchResultTableView.delegate = self;

    UITableViewController *uiTableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    uiTableViewController.tableView = self.searchResultTableView;

    NSLog(@"fetching businesses");
    [self fetchBusinesses];
    [self.searchResultTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"total rows: %d", self.businesses.count);
    return self.businesses.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"getting cell");
    RestaurantViewCell *restaurantViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RestaurantViewCell"];
    if (restaurantViewCell == nil) {
        restaurantViewCell = [[RestaurantViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"RestaurantViewCell"];
    }

    NSLog(@"businesses count (for cell view): %d", self.businesses.count);
    restaurantViewCell.textLabel.text = @"Osha's Thai";
    return restaurantViewCell;
}
@end
```

When I run I get logs as

```
2014-06-19 10:12:23.580 yelp[16008:70b] fetching businesses
2014-06-19 10:12:23.602 yelp[16008:70b] total rows: 0
2014-06-19 10:12:24.026 yelp[16008:70b] businesses count (after fetch): 20
```

Now since `self.businesses.count` is `0`, it never calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but when async call returns `self.businesses.count` is `20`.

**Question**
- What do I do so that `numberOfRowsInSection` and subsequently `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called when async call `[self.fetcBbusinesses]` is done?

Thanks

Comment: What's up with that random `uiTableViewController` in `viewDidLoad`? You aren't doing anything with it.

Comment: I got rid of `uiTableViewController`, it was really not doing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st - check your IB

All these outlets must be connected

[image: UITableView outlets]

2nd - add "reloadData" after this line

```
NSLog(@"businesses count (after fetch): %d", self.businesses.count);
```

You will get the code->

```
 [self.client searchWithTerm:@"Thai" success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
    self.businesses = response[@"businesses"];

    NSLog(@"businesses count (after fetch): %d", self.businesses.count);
    [self.searchResultTableView reloadData];
}                   failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error description]);
}];
```

I hope it's help you.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track:

`[self.searchResultTableView reloadData];` should take care of this.

If it does not reload it means your tableView is not connected to the property `searchResultTableView`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will only work if `fetchBusinesses` is synchronous.

```
[self fetchBusinesses];
[self.searchResultTableView reloadData];
```

However, it's not synchronous, which means you should only call `reloadData` AFTER you get a response.

```
- (void)fetchBusinesses {
    // You can register for Yelp API keys here: http://www.yelp.com/developers/manage_api_keys
    self.client = [[YelpClient alloc] initWithConsumerKey:kYelpConsumerKey consumerSecret:kYelpConsumerSecret accessToken:kYelpToken accessSecret:kYelpTokenSecret];

    [self.client searchWithTerm:@"Thai" success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
        self.businesses = response[@"businesses"];
        NSLog(@"businesses count (after fetch): %d", self.businesses.count);
        [self.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error description]);
    }];
}
```

Comment: I tried this way as well, but it still returns `total rows: 0`

Comment: Use a breakpoint to check if `searchResultsTableView` is nil.

Comment: Yes, it is. Where is the right place to construct it? and how?

Comment: Your code _implies_ with the `IBOutlet` that it was connected from a xib or storyboard. Check the connection.

Comment: I guess that's the problem, I do not have a `xib` file, nor I have created one, I guess I need to do that now

Comment: You don't _need_ to. Did you just copy and paste that property from some code sample?

Comment: If you want to make the table in code you need to change your property to be strong, `alloc` `init` the table view, and then add it as a subview of your view controller's view.

Comment: Wait... Does `SearchResultViewController` inherit from `UITableViewController`!?! If that's the case then delete the `searchResultTableView` property and just use `self.tableView`.